# new to open source

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Just wrapping up a C/C++ certificate program at UCSD.  I would like to get involved with the ROS project.  I have started looking over the Get Involved pages and the Hand Off list.

I have never worked on an open source project before.  I would like to start out by testing and fixing bugs.  Can anyone outline which actual steps I need to take to get started.  I am looking over the above pages but it still seems a bit general as far as what I need to do to start out.

I know I need to download a stack, but which sections do I need to follow in order to check in the code etc,  Is the code referenced from the github site I create?  I do not need any handholding just an outline on the important sections to follow.

Thanks

Joe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63640/new-to-open-source/) by [jpitz31](https://answers.ros.org/users/757/jpitz31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, I'd say you'll want to spend a LOT of time setting up and using the software so you know its operation very well. Once you feel you are really ready to contribute via testing, bug fixes etc you might want to look at these resources,

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Get%20Involved

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Get%20Involved/Handoff%20List

While for some of the newest happenings in the ROS community have a look here,

http://planet.ros.org/

http://www.ros.org/news/

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [cbgrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/4978/cbgrey/) with karma: 38 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's great that you are interested in volunteering your time to help with an open source project! The way to contribute heavily depends on which of the many projects you start working with.

Since you mentioned github you could find a stack that is already hosted on there (such as [camera calibration](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/tree/groovy-devel/camera_calibration)), look through the [issues list](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues), create a fork, create your own branch with fixes, then [submit a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) to the project owners.

The biggest thing is to start by contributing to something you are interested in. I would stay away from sensor drivers if you do not have easy access to the sensor. This could even mean integrating a capability that does not yet exist in the ROS ecosystem. Another idea would be to take a useful stack that has not received much attention lately and convert it from using robuild to catkin. And don't forget that writing or updating documentation is very appreciated as well.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8